# IFTTT Status check URL and Key

Tags: php, codeigniter, ifttt

I am trying to implement the IFTTT in my website. I have created the Service. 
I have created the API for status and test setup check with given type, like

API-> abc.com/api/ifttt/v1/status & abc.com/api/ifttt/v1/test/setup

1. Using CI and routing for this purpose.
2. Added following header in it Host, COntent-type, IFTTT-Channel-Key, Accept-Encoding
3. Channel key is taken when creating the applet as i remember. its at the end of an url

But in response i am getting following error for status check when doing the endpoint test
    - Valid request is in green.
    - with invalid channel key in red with status code 401 is shown

Please help me out.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the status/setup endpoint test :

- `valid request` is checked when your return status code 200 when a correct `IFTTT-Channel-Key` is sent in the headers
- `with invalid channel key` is checked when you return status code 401 when an incorrect `IFTTT-Channel-Key` is sent in the headers

For instance a request with invalid channel key would be :

Request :

```
GET https://example.com/api/ifttt/v1/status HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Accept-Charset: utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: IFTTT-Protocol/v1
IFTTT-Test-Mode: 1
IFTTT-Channel-Key: INVALID
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
date: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 23:04:28 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
content-type: application/json
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-length: 0
connection: close
```

You have to check that `IFTTT-Channel-Key` header value and send status code 200 if it's correct & 401 if incorrect.

`IFTTT-Channel-Key` is the Service API Key you can find under `API`/`General` tab :

[image]

Service API key is unique per channel

Comment: i tried by putting the service key also, bu its not working, i am getting same response code.

Comment: Did you check the ifttt key header and return 401 when it doesnt match the service key ?

Comment: I am confused a little. I have made the file for status. I put the header flags including the ifttt Service key. And then i check from IFTTT for Endpoint Testing. I am not using any type of authentication yet. Do i need to check for any kind of key from IFTTT for status also. Please guide.

Comment: For the /status & /setup endpoint, when you handle the request do the following : check that header `IFTTT-Channel-Key` is present, check that `IFTTT-Channel-Key` is equal to your service API key (if not return 401 unauthorized), return the stuff according to the API (status or endpoint). This is not about authentication, this is about returning 401 status code when the request you handle from IFTTT hasn't the right value for  `IFTTT-Channel-Key` header

Comment: got the mistake, IFTTT was sending 2 request, one valid and other invalid, which i was not checking. Now it works correct for status, test/status and user info. But again got struck in triggers. Its sending 7 requests and not able to figure diffrecne between each one except the Authorization key.